# Does there exists a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ such that$f$ is $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{B}$ measurable iif $f$ is continuous?

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $f$ be a function from $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{F}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is a sigma-algebra and $\mathcal{B}$ denotes the Borel sigma-algebra.
>
> Does there exists a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ such that $f$ is $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{B}$ measurable if and only if $f$ is continuous?

I think this is sigma-algebra does not exists, because we could always make some construction such that we take one point, say $x$ in the range of $f$ and project it on i.e. $x-1$. This will make our function discontinuous, but still measurable (I think). However, I do not know how to write this down formally and if it is correct. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, such a $\sigma$-algebra does not exist.

Suppose it does exist; then, since $f(x)=x$ is continuous, then, for any $a\in\mathbb R$, $(a,\infty)\in\mathcal{B}$, therefore $$(a,\infty)=f^{-1}(a,\infty)\in \mathcal{F}.$$ This shows that $\mathcal{B}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$, hence $\chi_{(0,\infty)}$ is measurable, but is is not continuous. This is a contradiction.

Comment: What do you mean by $\chi_{(0,\infty)}$?

Comment: @Nescrio, the indicator function of $(0,\infty)$.